# Is upgraded icebreaker strength per subroutine

Tags: android-netrunner

If I pay credits to upgrade the strength of my ice breaker do I have to pay to do that for every subroutine or does the upgraded strength last for the whole encounter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whole encounter.
From the rules (emphasis theirs):

> This strength increase lasts **only** while the current piece of ice is
>   being encountered, unless otherwise noted by card abilities. After an
>   encounter with a piece of ice, the icebreaker’s strength returns to
>   the value shown on its card

Answer (score 1):

For most icebreakers, the boosted strength lasts for the ice, and is reset at the end of that encounter, however there are some specific ice breakers that work differently, [Gordian Blade](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01043) being the most notable example, the strength getting boosted for the run, though others like [Study Guide](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08028) don't boost like most others, they power up permanently through counter gain.

There are also other effects that modify ice breakers strength for different periods, like [Security Chip](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09046), and [Net-Ready Eyes](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08047). These effects have their own time limit placed on them, and that time limit is independent of the ice's boost ability.